# How to update triples in Protégé?

Tags: sparql, rdf, protege

I'm trying a very simple SPARQL update in both Protégé 4.3 and 5b24:

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
DELETE {?s ?p ?o}
WHERE { ?s rdfs:isDefinedBy ?o }
```

It throws the following error:

> An error was thrown: org.openrdf.query.MalformedQueryException:
>   Encountered " "delete" "DELETE "" at line 5, column 1. Was expecting
>   one of: "base" ... "prefix" ... "select" ... "construct" ...
>   "describe" ... "ask" ...

My questions are:

1. Is any update allowed in Protégé? and if not
2. What are the alternative file-based ways to achieve this? (including non-SPARQL means in Protégé)

Comment: There is a suggestion [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30818173/malformed-sparql-delete-query) that Protégé does not support updates. But in the event that this is not the case, perhaps try [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11456102/sparql-query-delete-all-statements). Alternatively, and assuming that you are working in a Java environment, you might consider using the JENA API -There's a [ARQ - a SPARQL Processor for Jena](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/query/index.html) which supports SPARQL/Updates.

Comment: If you want to use SPARQL, Protégé 4 is probably not a good choice as it is not RDF-based.  Protégé 3 may work better or use other RDF-based tools such as Jena, TopBraid Composer, etc.

Comment: Well, I used TopBraid finally. `DELETE` didn't throw an error but didn't actually work either. However, `INSERT` worked fine. Anyway, I'm still interested how it can be done in Protégé and I'm fine if i have to use something else, if not SPARQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error in your DELETE graph pattern.  `?p` is not bound in the `WHERE` clause, so the `DELETE` graph pattern will fail to find a match.  The following would delete triples with `rdfs:isDefinedBy` as the property:

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
DELETE { ?s rdfs:isDefinedBy ?o }
WHERE { ?s rdfs:isDefinedBy ?o }
```

Guaranteed to work for TopBraid Composer, and could work for Protégé.

Comment: I'm not able to understand why this pattern is wrong. Asking to delete every triple where the predicate is `rdfs:isDefinedBy` is just how SPARQL is supposed to work. And if the pattern is wrong, why then it works with `SELECT`? In fact this is how I see what I'm about to delete. (I understand that `SELECT` does't work on triple patterns, while `DELETE` and `WHERE` do) I would really appreciate if you could elaborate. (I confirm that with your suggestion, it works in TBC; it doesn't work in Protégé, but there I don't think that  any UPDATE can work)

Comment: The way pattern matching in SPARQL works is that the `WHERE` clause defines the variable bindings that can be used in `INSERT`, `DELETE`, `CONSTRUCT`, etc.  If variables are not bound, such for `p` in your case, then DELETE does not have any triples it can create. All of them would be`{?s nil ?o}`, which is not a valid triple.